# Difficulty in calculating output impedance for the emitter follower

Tags: bjt, emitter-follower

[image: http://i66.tinypic.com/2wf95yh.jpg]
This is the pic for the emitter follower using BJT.

Is there a direct way of calculating output impedance instead of the way proceeded in the text book?

Textbook procedure:
[image: http://tinypic.com/r/29qcuu9/9]

Ps: The images are of >2mb and couldn't be uploaded directly. excuse me for any inconvenience.

Comment: What does "direct way"?

Comment: The textbook's result could have been determined trivially by inspection of Figure 5.39 since \$V_i = 0\$ for output impedance analysis...

Comment: @MartinPetrei What I meant by direct way was to just use Vout/Iout to get Zout

Comment: @Null But the author made the circuit of Fig-5.39 after some manipulation.(Please refer to the second image once)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there is another way - for my opinion, much simpler. My recommendation is to recalculate the procedure you would apply during measurements.

- At first, forget for the moment RE and calculate - as a first step - the input resistance at the emitter node. Because the Resistor RB is in series to the base we can take into account this resustor RB at the end.
- Hence, we simply have the dynamic resistance between B and E as seen from the emitter (Ohm`s law): **r,e=v,be/ie.**
- If we set **ie=(hfe+1)*ib** and **v,be/ib=hie** we arrive at **r,e=hie/(hfe+1)**.
- Setting **(hfe+1)=hfe** we have **r,e=hie/hfe=1/gm** (gm:transconductance)
- This expression is, of course, identical to the common-base input resistance.
- Final step: The desired overall input resistance for the common-collector stge is **r,in,cc=(r,e+RB)||RE.**
- The resistor r,e=1/gm is nothing else than **r,e=Vt/Ic** (Vt:temperature voltage, Ic:DC current)
- Comment: The above derivation applies for the case that no signal source is connected to the base coupling capacitor. If a signal source is connected with an internal source resistance Rs we have to replace in the given formula RB by the parallel combination RB||Rs.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, knowing the circuit topology and element values, the best way to find the input impedance is analytically.

The "direct" form (measuring \$v_o\$ and \$i_o\$) is applicable to the physical circuit, taking care to passivate the signal sources, and then to measure the output impedance. You can also apply other methods.

However, knowing the [impedance reflection](http://s3.amazonaws.com/cramster-resource/967_n_8915.pdf), it is essential to understanding many, more complicated than this simple common emitter amplifier analog circuits.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to calculate Zout by using Vout/Iout?

Comment: You can apply an input signal with known amplitude and measure the output signal of the amplifier, without charge. Then, you connect a variable load and as reduce its value, the output signal is reduced. When the output signal reaches half the original value, the variable load having the same value as the output impedance.

Comment: If you work a bit on this idea, you'll see that it is not necessary to reduce the output signal exactly half of its value.